# React - Failing to give the same state to 2 elements with the same id (card and modal)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-state

I am rendering some cards and upon clicking a card, I have the corresponding modal. Both the card and its modal have a heart icon and I want to mark both as "favorite" when either of them is clicked. I have a "favoriteBeers" array, where I want to push the favorite beers. I also have another piece of state named "favorite" and this one is boolean. The issue is that this state seems to be reversed (it is false when it's supposed to be true and the other way around). Also, only one item seems to be in the favorites array, no matter how may items I try to set as favorite.

I have lifted the array state on the root component, this is the piece of code that lies there:

```
  const [favoriteBeers, setFavoriteBeers] = useState([]);

  const handleSetFavorite = id => {
    setFavoriteBeers([...favoriteBeers, beers.find(beer => beer.id === id)]);
  };

  const handleRemoveFavorite = id => {
    setFavoriteBeers(favoriteBeers.filter(beer => beer.id !== id));
    
  };
```

I also have one component for the card, and one for its modal. I have an identical function in both components:

```
const [isFavorite, setIsFavorite] = useState(false);

 if (!isFavorite) {
        setIsFavorite(true);
        handleSetFavorite(id);
      } else {
        setIsFavorite(false);
        handleRemoveFavorite(id);
      }
    };

//the icon that calls the function
<IconButton aria-label='add to favorites'>
     {!isFavorite ? (
       <FavoriteBorderIcon
          onClickCapture={e => handleIconClick(e, beer.id)}
        />
      ) : (
         <FavoriteIcon onClickCapture={e => handleIconClick(e, beer.id)} />
  )}
</IconButton>
```

I have also prepared a codesandbox [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/rough-meadow-0gqm9?file=/src/App.js) with the components, thanks in advance

Comment: I don't see where you're accessing the favorite list to initially set your state for isFavorite...

Comment: I've given it a quick look. You have some issues. The basic one is you keep different states for `favourites` within the card you have `const [isFavorite, setIsFavorite] = useState(false);` so it is not coming from the beer.
In `App.js` you pass down favoriteBeers to `Home` and you do nothing with that information. So I would make sure to put all the logic together and not split it in different components.

Comment: @JasonGoemaat The isFavorite is mainly for the visual effect, where I alternate between two icons. I set the initial state to false. I had tried to do it in the handleSetFavorite and handleRemoveFavorite, but it would affect all the cards and decided to put it into the BeerCard (the card component) and the BeerCardExpanded (the modal component)

Comment: @R3ctor I did it this way because I have another component called Favorites that I don't have implemented yet. I tried to put this in the `App.js` component but it affected all the cards and I decided to split the state, so that I will handle the favorites array in the root component, and the `isFavorite` state for the individual component in the card and the modal respectively.

Comment: It really doesn't matter how you structure your data as log as it is not duplicated, as it can easily get out of sync as it is happening to you right now. You can have an array with all the beers with a `favourite` flag, or keep favourites list with the ids. Whatever but have it only in one place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One problem is that in `<Home>` your `isFavorite` prop is `undefined` since `<App>` isn't passing such a thing. Also you're not using this prop value (currently `undefined`) to initialize the `<BeerCard>` or `<BeerCardExpanded>` components.

Second problem - the code below is only updating a components own `isFavorite` state and calling `handleSetFavorite`, since each component has it's own local `isFavorite` state.

```
 if (!isFavorite) {
    setIsFavorite(true);
    handleSetFavorite(id);
  }
```

For example when `<BeerCard>` flips it's `isFavorite` state, `<BeerCardExpanded>` doesn't. So I've removed these local states and directly used `props.isFavorite` instead.

---

### Here is [updated sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/gallant-germain-rn6ye?file=/src/components/Home.js)

I've added this method in `<Home>`:

```
const isFavorite = (beer, favoriteBeers) => {
   return favoriteBeers.includes(beer);
};
```

Which is used to pass proper boolean value for  the same for `isFavorite` prop of both  `<BeerCard>` (`isFavorite={isFavorite(beer, favoriteBeers)}`)

And `<BeerCardExpanded>` (`isFavorite={isFavorite(isClicked, favoriteBeers)}`) components.

---

I've used rest params syntax `...props` just to avoid renaming `isFavorite` prop and have minimal changes. You can improvise the whole thing.

Comment: This is not working. If you favourite a beer from the modal, the list does not get updated.

Comment: Ah you're right. The other way is working. I didn't check the backwards. Looks like your original list is not getting re-rendered when state is updated

Comment: @StelKizi check the updated sandbox. the problem was their local states getting out of sync

Comment: Precisely what I said. There are several ways to improve it.
1 -  Move all the information to a custom hook `useBeers` that could potentially return the all beers, favourite beers, toggleFavourite function. This will allow you to move logic from `App.js `to Home avoiding prop drilling.
2 - For something more advanced use redux.

Comment: I see, thank you! I need the logic in `App.js` to pass the `favoriteBeers` in a `favorites` page. Or at least this is the only way I know how to do it. I don't really know Redux yet, but definitely will learn it after this project. Thanks a lot guys!